# preg_match with number PHP

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-match

When I use this :

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,10}(\.[0-9]{1,9})?$/', 0.0001);
```

The return value is 1, and when I use this :

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,10}(\.[0-9]{1,9})?$/', 0.00001);
```

The return value is 0.

Somebody could say me why please ? Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because small floating point numbers are normally displayed using exponential notation, so `0.00001` is converted to `1.0E-5`, which doesn't match the regexp. You can see this if you simply do:

```
echo 0.00001;
```

Regular expressions should be used with strings, not numbers.

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,10}(\.[0-9]{1,9})?$/', '0.00001');
```